# ¿Por qué me imprime esos valores el arreglo?

Tags: array, c, punteros

En el siguiente código, tal como está, el arreglo **lista** se imprime con 2 valores extra: -1 y 78 (está iterando 7 veces el bucle) y no sé por qué. Si alguien me aclara la situación se lo agradecería.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    
    char cadena[]="¡Es una cadena!";
        char *aptr_cadena;
    int lista[5]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int *aptr_int;
        int i;
    
    /*Acceso al arreglo de tipo char*/
    aptr_cadena=cadena;  // ----->>>Si comento esta sentencia el arreglo me imprime 1, 2, -3, 4 y 5
        //printf("Antes del cambio, cadena contiene: %s\n", cadena);
        //  printf("Antes del cambio, cadena[4] contiene: %c\n", cadena[4]);
    //  *(aptr_cadena + 4)='U';
    //printf("Despues del cambio, cadena[4] contiene: %c\n", cadena[4]);
    //printf("Despues del cambio, cadena contiene: %s\n", cadena);
    /*Acceso al arreglo de ti po int*/
    aptr_int=lista;
    //printf("Antes del cambio, lista[2] contiene: %d\n", lista[2]);
        *(aptr_int + 2)=-3;
    printf("Despues del cambio, lista[2] contiene: %d\n", lista[2]);
            
            i=0;
            printf("Despues del cambio, lista contiene:");
            while(lista[i]){
                printf("%d ", lista[i]);
            i++;
}   printf("\n\ni vale ahora=%d", i);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```c
while(lista[i]) //Equivalente a lista[i] != 0
{
      printf("%d ", lista[i]);
      i++;
}
```

En el *array* no hay ningún elemento que sea cero, por lo tanto, ocurrirá un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (pasarse de los límites del *array*) y esto genera un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), así que puedes esperar cualquier resultado en tiempo de ejecución, puede que funcione o puede que no.

Es más, corres el riesgo de **intentar** acceder a direcciones de memoria que no están libres (es decir, fueron asignados para otros procesos), haciendo que el sistema operativo mate el proceso actual.

La condición del bucle debería ser:

```c
while(i < 5) 
{
      printf("%d ", lista[i]);
      i++;
}
```

De este modo, nos aseguramos de recorrer de forma correcta el *array* y evita un desborde.

Comment: En sistemas operativos modernos, como Windows (XP o superior), Linux, etc, generalmente no accederías a la memoria de otros procesos, pero si a la memoria de tu propio proceso. Si sales del espacio de memoria asignado a TU proceso, generarías un _General Protection Fault_ u otro error relacionado con la memoria protegida.

Comment: @jachguate Gracias por su comentario, he editado la respuesta para aclarar eso.